# не могу вернуть данные из функции

Tags: python, рекурсия

как получить на выходе функции subset1 и subset2 если они равны
согласно коду я это возвращаю здесь

```
        if sum(subset1) == sum(subset2):
            return subset1, subset2
```

однако из за рекурсии я не знаю как это получит на выходе выполнения всех рекурсий данной функции. Единственный вариант который знаю я это ловить как исключении, но это как то не особо изящно

```
def find_two_equal_subset(subset1, subset2=None,):
    if not subset2:
        for i, item in enumerate(subset1):
            find_two_equal_subset(subset1[:i] + subset1[i + 1:], [item])
    else:
        if sum(subset1) == sum(subset2):
            return subset1, subset2
        for i, item in enumerate(subset1):
            set = find_two_equal_subset(subset1[:i] + subset1[i + 1:], subset2 + [item])


print(find_two_equal_subset([15, 5, 20, 10, 35, 15, 10]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Питоне есть редкая особенность: он умеет возвращать несколько результатов. Я не про `return a, b` а про `yield`, который "возвращает" результат, но продолжает выполнение функции. Функция становится [генератором](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator), который вызывается в цикле или может быть переделан в список. Почитайте также про [yield from](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380):

```
def find_two_equal_subset(subset1, subset2=None,):
    if not subset2:
        for i, item in enumerate(subset1):
            yield from find_two_equal_subset(subset1[:i] + subset1[i + 1:], [item])
    else:
        if sum(subset1) == sum(subset2):
            yield subset1, subset2
        for i, item in enumerate(subset1):
            yield from find_two_equal_subset(subset1[:i] + subset1[i + 1:], subset2 + [item])

for a, b in find_two_equal_subset([15, 5, 20, 10, 35, 15, 10]):
    print(a, b)
```

Вашу функцию можно упростить совместив ветки `if` и `else`:

```
def find_two_equal_subset(subset1, subset2=[]):
    if sum(subset1) == sum(subset2):
        yield subset1, subset2
    for i, item in enumerate(subset1):
        yield from find_two_equal_subset(subset1[:i] + subset1[i + 1:], subset2 + [item])

for a, b in find_two_equal_subset([15, 5, 20, 10, 35, 15, 10]):
    print(a, b)
```

Второй аргумент - деталь реализации. Спрячем её:

```
def find_two_equal_subset(set_):

    def find_two_equal_subset(subset1, subset2):
        if sum(subset1) == sum(subset2):
            yield subset1, subset2
        for i, item in enumerate(subset1):
            yield from find_two_equal_subset(subset1[:i] + subset1[i + 1:], subset2 + [item])

    return find_two_equal_subset(set_, [])

for a, b in find_two_equal_subset([15, 5, 20, 10, 35, 15, 10]):
    print(a, b)
```

Исходный вариант порождает одни и те же пары множеств много раз. Рекурсию можно было бы поправить, но она не нужна. `itertools.product` умеет перебирать подмножества нерекурсивно:

```
import itertools

def find_two_equal_subset(set_):

    def subset(p, j):
        return (a for a, i in zip(set_, p) if i == j)

    for p in itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=len(set_)):
        if sum(subset(p, 0)) == sum(subset(p, 1)):
            yield list(subset(p, 0)), list(subset(p, 1))

for a, b in find_two_equal_subset([15, 5, 20, 10, 35, 15, 10]):
    print(a, b)
```

Comment: круто, спасибо, это то что нужно! сразу появился еще вопрос - как можно вернуть только первый найденый сабсет?

Comment: `next(find_two_equal_subset(...))` или `break` в цикле.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужен только один вариант можно обойтись без рекурсии, c помощью сортировки и цикла. Сортировка помогает поровну распределить значения. Цикл раскидывает значения по сабсетам в зависимости от того который из них меньше.

**не на всех наборах данных работает**

```
def find_two_equal_subset(set):
    subset1=[]
    subset2=[]
    for n in sorted(set, reverse=True):
        if sum(subset1) < sum(subset2):
           subset1.append(n)
        else:
           subset2.append(n)
    if (sum(subset1) == sum(subset2)): 
      return sum(subset1), sum(subset2)
```

Этот и другие варианты решения можно посмотреть [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB)

Comment: Не работает для `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`.

Comment: да, действиельно в некоторых случаях будет не работь - алгоритм слишком прост для подобного